# Google Sheets Vlookup not working when Apps Script adds a line to range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gs-vlookup

I've got a basic vlookup set up in a spreadsheet which is updated by a form. It is pulling data from a page that is updated by Apps script. My vlookup looks like this

```
=VLOOKUP($B$3,'Checklist Log'!A:AZ,2,false)
```

The 'checklist log' tab has column headers along row 1 and dates down column A which are populated by

```
=SORT(Sheet1!A2:A,1,FALSE)
```

from sheet1 where the form submits to.

Whenever a form is submitted my Apps script adds a row under row 1 and then copies the cells from the checklist tab and then clears the checklist tab.

I think a possible solution would be to make my apps script insert new cells from `b2:AZ2` instead of the whole line but i can't seem to find code to do that. So how can I fix that?

Comment: the ranges wont break if you instead insert rows above the last

Comment: So, would you find the last row in the range, then use [Google Documentation Link - insertRowBefore(rowNumber)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertRowBefore(Integer))

Comment: So like Sandy says get it to paste the new info at the bottom of the range? Then I wouldn't even need to insert a row which then shouldn't mess up my vlookup. Or insert row above row 2 instead of below row 1? my vlookup is looking in the whole coulumn for A:AZ.

Comment: Even if I re enter the vlookup formula it still doesn't return a value for the rows that were created by the apps script. all i get is the "Error
Did not find value '42226.53652' in VLOOKUP evaluation." The cells are formatted the same as the cells that work. here is a link to view my sheet. The problem is the vlookups in tab "Audit Lookup" referencing tab "checklist Log" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R_SfxrAg35eVAoypaopKL-QjnkVHJgtBiL82GYnr9Kk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: So i figured that the script that was inserting a line was the problem, so I created a new script to copy and past it to the next available row at the bottom. All works fine except the Vlookup that is trying to reference the timestamp. Now I have figured that it is probably a formatting issue as if I play around with the formatting enough it recognizes it. Its not even the format that makes a difference, its the amount of times that I change it. It usually recognizes it when I change it to Automatic, but not if I change it the first time. Its quite odd behaviour. I'm officially stumped

Answer (score 1):

Reference format:  `VLOOKUP(search_key, range, index)`

Failing example:  `VLOOKUP(C5,G16:H18,2)`

Passing example:   `VLOOKUP(C5,G16:H19,2)`

I had a similar error when I attempted to lookup a value in the last row of the range (i.e., row 18). Based on other peoples' suggestions, I tried changing the formats of the values in the range cells, but to no avail. I then increased the range to include one additional row (i.e., `range = G16:H19`), and everything worked fine.